# How do I create XML's dateTime format using vbscript?

Tags: datetime, vbscript

I need to create the date and time of extraction in the following format.

```
extractDate='2011-10-18T12:00:00.000000'
```

What is the best way, using vbscript / asp3 to do this? I was just thinking of hard-coding the end portion of .000000 since this is not a horse race LOL

Thanks.

So Far I am starting with something like;

```
xmlDateTime = FormatDateTime(Now(),0)
xmlDateTime = Replace(xmlDateTime, " PM", "")
xmlDateTime = Replace(xmlDateTime, " AM", "")
Response.Write xmlDateTime & "<br>"
```

UPDATE:

My potential solution:

```
xmlDateTime = FormatDateTime(Now(),0)
xmlDateTime = Replace(xmlDateTime, " PM", "")
xmlDateTime = Replace(xmlDateTime, " AM", "")
Response.Write xmlDateTime & "<br>"
splitDateTime = Split(xmlDateTime, " ")

xmlDate = splitDateTime(0)
xmlTime = splitDateTime(1)

strYear = DatePart("yyyy",xmlDate)
strMonth = DatePart("m",xmlDate)
strDay = DatePart("d",xmlDate)


Response.Write strYear & "<br>"
Response.Write strMonth & "<br>"
Response.Write strDay & "<br>"

xmlDateTime = strYear & "-" & strMonth & "-" & strDay & "T" & xmlTime & ".000000"
Response.write xmlDateTime & "<br>"
```

Comment: Simply removing "AM" and "PM" from the string will give you an incorrect time string the second half of the day. Date formats with AM/PM use a 12-hour clock whereas you need a 24-hour clock.

Comment: TY - I am going to go with the best answer below too. THanks all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to construct the date string manually.

```
Function dd(str)
  dd = Right("0" & str, 2)
End Function

d = Now
extractDate = Year(d) & "-" & dd(Month(d)) & "-" & dd(Day(d)) & "T" _
  & dd(Hour(d)) & ":" & dd(Minute(d)) & ":" & dd(Second(d)) & ".000000"
```

Comment: So awesome too! Does a good programmer always need to think in terms of code separation no matter what the language?

Comment: It helps avoiding maintenance headaches.